# Finding a module's directory

Tags: python, module, dirname

How can I find what directory a module has been imported from, as it needs to load a data file which is in the same directory.

edit:

combining several answers:

```
module_path = os.path.dirname(imp.find_module(self.__module__)[1])
```

got me what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modules directory by specifying `module_name` as string *i.e. without actually importing the module* then use

```
def get_dir(module_name):
    import os,imp
    (file, pathname, description) = imp.find_module(module_name)
    return os.path.dirname(pathname)

print get_dir('os')
```

output:

```
C:\Python26\lib
```

---

foo.py

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

bar.py

```
import foo
import os
print os.path.dirname(foo.__file__)
foo.foo()
```

output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
yourmodule.__file__
```

and if you want to find the module an object was imported from:

```
myobject.__module__
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to the module's file is in `module.__file__`. You can use that with `os.path.dirname` to get the directory.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work within the module eg, in the __init__ method, print self.__file__ fails, any other ideas?

Comment: self is not the module it is the instance of a class. The module is the name of the file ie the name used in an import

Answer (score 1):

Using the re module as an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> path = re.__file__
>>> print path
C:\python26\lib\re.pyc
>>> import os.path
>>> print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(path))
C:\python26\lib
```

Note that if the module is in your current working directory ("CWD"), you will get just a relative path e.g. `foo.py`. I make it a habit of getting the absolute path immediately just in case the CWD gets changed before the module path gets used.